# Dots Indicator in ListView Horizontal Scroll in Flutter

Tags: listview, user-interface, flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

I want the listView to have a dots indicator, based on the first listView Item position, can it do that?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/collinjackson/4fddbfa2830ea3ac033e34622f278824

Answer (score 3):

It is called a carousel. Checkout the plugins [carousel_slider](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/carousel_slider) and [carousel_pro](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/carousel_pro)

Comment: thanks! sorry, i guess this isn't like the picture :(

Comment: Then please explain more. The pic looks like a carousel to me